# Move Add to Cart form to right column

Tags: magento-1.9, template

http://computercity.com/cryorig-c7-40-5-cfm-cpu-cooler.html

How would I go about moving all the product ordering details:

(availability, quantity, price, submit button)

to the right hand column within the "col-right sidebar col-sm-3" class DIV?

I've attempted editing the template files but have had no success.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your root template for the product view is set to 2-columns. I would suggest to set it to 1 column.

Got to your `local.xml` and have this code:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view translate="label">
```

Now, go to `catalog/product/view.phtml` and move blocks as required.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that you have using a theme **smartwave porto** theme and your product details page layout is **2columns -right** *(2-columns-right.phtml).*

If you want to move ***availability, price*** then it cannot be issue but if you move that *`div.add-to-box`* mean ***AddtoCart ,wishlist link,qty*** etc then it become create issues. Bcoz using this input fields,buttons a form `[ <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> ]` are  submitting

SO suggestion to change page layout to 1colum as  [Adarsh Khatri describe](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/120257/4564)